# Increasing Activity loading time

Tags: android

I have two Activities A and B. Activity A will start Activity B. Am doing some UI initialization, db query and local storage read operation in onCreate of Activity B. My problem is Activity B takes long time to come visible. Is that because of such operations in onCreate? I want at least my UI changes to visible first. Please guide me

Comment: Yeah. You can run the heavy operation in the other thread and then update the UI.

Comment: Thanks. Shall I do the UI changes in onCreate and other operations in onResume state of activity? After which state activity is visible to user?

Comment: No. Check the activity's lifecycle clearly. onResume() is called just before the screen becomes visible. So even if you do heavy operations in onResume() there would be no difference either. Either follow the below answer or use asynctask. You can have options to do this or create your own thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate perform heavy tasks in different Thread/handler/AsyncTask. For Example

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    // do other gui initialization
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.post(new Runnable{
        public void run(){
            // do your heave tasks
        }
    });
}
```